# Incorporating quantity of points in median

Tags: median, exploratory-data-analysis

I have multiple datasets with a variable amount of measure points.
I want to sort these datasets after the median of their points, but also incorporate how many points were measured. Medians from just a few points should be punished. But having a lot of points shouldn't favor in the end.

So if my median is m and |m| is the amount of points that build m:
 `m * f(|m|) * |m|`

I guess it should be a function with `lim x->inf f(x) = 1`.

I can construct myself any function that suits my needs, but is there any function that is normally used for this? Some function that is widely known for doing the thing I want to do?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking. Are you looking for some type of multivariate median function?

Comment: I would say more of adjusting my results.
My Datasets are results of an algorithm. It's always the same algorithm, but different parameters. Now I want to compare these results. The results could look like this:
Result 1: 1 hit of 70%. Result 2: 40 hits and a median of 60%.
Result 1 has the higher median but because it's just one hit result 2 is actually more interesting for me. 
So I want my sorting to respect the amount of hits for each result.

Comment: Oh and I know that I can just construct a function to do that for me, but the question is there default function to try that. Something that is widely used in the statistics community.

Comment: The short answer is no.  The reason is that you are asking how to *rank* data based on *two* quantities.  There is no unique way to do that and any such ranking is tantamount to a procedure that trades off losses attributed to the two variables.  This is a FAQ but, for the reasons I just gave, has never been answered.

Comment: I see the point. I will then just construct me a function that suits my personal needs.
Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @whuber What’s wrong with some kind of dictionary-style ordering where, if there is a tie on the median (like the first letter of the word), get the tiebreaker from the sample size (like the second letter of a word)?

Comment: @Dave There's nothing "wrong" about it--it's just one arbitrary solution chosen out of a large number of possible solutions.